# Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

```
        <?php
            $name= $_POST["dbname"];
            $pass= $_POST["dbpass"];
            $rname= $_POST["rootname"];
            $rpass=$_POST["rootpass"];

            if ($rname='leave blank for default root name' or $name='')
                {
                    $rname="root";
                }
            if ($rpass='leave blank if no password assigned')
                {
                    $rpass='';
                }

            $con = mysql_connect("localhost", $rname, $rpass);

            if (!$con)
                {

                  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
                }

                    if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE {$name}",$con))
                        {
                          echo "Database created";
                         }
                        else
                          {
                              echo "Error creating database: " . mysql_error();
                          }
                    (mysql_query("DATABASEPASSWORD {$pass}",$con));


                mysql_close($con);      
        ?>
```

this is the php script i am using to create database,i am passing rootname=root and rootpass=toor

but i am getting an error

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO) in /var/www/webdefender/script/dbcreate.php on
>   line 17 Could not connect: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
>   (using password: NO)

but when i use

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", 'root','toor' );
```

it works fine

Please help

Comment: If password is set, you must have to specify password when you connect with server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're assigning values in your first 2 checks instead of checking them for equality.

```
$a = 1; // assigning
$a == 1; // this is a check if 1 is $a is equal to 1
```

So you're basically resetting your $rpass value to '' (empty string) in:

```
if ($rpass='leave blank if no password assigned')
{
   $rpass='';
}
```

Change your checks to use == and it will work.

Please to be aware that using root access from scripts is a HUGE security hazard.

Comment: Same thing goes for your $rname check btw.

Answer (score 0):

Don't  use or  use below code near `if ($rname='')`

```
if ($rname='')
{
    $rname="root";
}
```

Comment: if you use this code, nothing will change (compared to the current situation): it will still not work.

Answer (score 0):

it's general when U use if like this

```
if($a=b)
```

always return true and $a have the value b 

 the right Syntax is

```
if($a==b)
```

so if and only if $a value = b it return true